# Extra Padding On Top Of My Images

Tags: android, whitespace, android-linearlayout

I have a LinearLayout (Horizontal) that I am using to display 3 ImageViews. When I first add the ImageViews the last one is shrunk because the images are too big to fit 3 across. Here is what my designer screen looks like:

[image: after initially adding the three images]

Notice the third image is shrunk.

To fix this issue I set the following attributes on each ImageView.

```
width: 0dp
weight: 1
```

Here is how my images look after setting those attributes:

[image: after setting attributes]

The problem I am running into is even though the images have been *shrunk* there is still *space* at the top and bottom as shown by the blue rectangle in the following image:

[image: padding]

My question is, why is this *extra* padding there and how can I get rid of it?

Thank you

UPDATE - adding my layout file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:background="@color/app_background_color"
android:contentDescription="@string/game_image_button"
android:gravity="center"
tools:context=".EasyActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView02"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/game_image_button"
        android:src="@drawable/ruler200x200" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/game_image_button"
        android:src="@drawable/ruler200x200" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/game_image_button"
        android:src="@drawable/ruler200x200" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Just curious, what size is your original image? I mean is it a 'x by x' square image?

Comment: It is 200x200 pixels and it's located in drawable_hdpi

Comment: if you post the code for the whole layout would be easier to understand

Comment: done. please see my original post

Answer (score 0):

ImageViews support different ScaleTypes, the default is `FIT_CENTER`.  [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) are the other options.  `FIT_CENTER` means its going to start out with height and width equal to your image (what your images looked like in the first screen shot before you added weight).  What I believe happened is that it then resized the width of the image based on your `layout_weight`, and maintained the image's aspect ratio by shrinking it to fit the new width.  It left the height to be the original height and centered the result.

I think one of the other scale types would do what you want.  Maybe `CENTER` or `CENTER_INSIDE`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code

```
<Imageview.....
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
..../>
```